# Bash: preserve string with spaces input on command line?

Tags: string, bash, input

I'd like to allow a string to be captured with spaces, so that:

```
echo -n "Enter description: "
read input
echo $input
```

Would produce:

```
> Enter description: My wonderful description!
> My wonderful description!
```

Possible?

Comment: What does it produce on your system? You should probably quote `"$input"`, but it's not clear what error you're seeing.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, I wasn't receiving an error, but the string was split at the first whitespace.  `"$input"`, this was helpful!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main thing to worry about is that when you refer to a variable without enclosing it in double-quotes, the shell does word splitting (splits it into multiple words wherever there's a space or other whitespace character), as well as wildcard expansion. Solution: use double-quotes whenever you refer to a variable (e.g. `echo "$input"`).

Second, `read` will trim leading and trailing whitespace (i.e. spaces at the beginning and/or end of the input). If you care about this, use `IFS= read` (this essentially wipes out its definition of whitespace, so nothing gets trimmed). You might also want to use `read`'s `-r` ("raw") option, so it doesn't try to interpret backslash at the end of a line as a continuation character.

Finally, I'd recommend using `read`'s `-p` option to supply the prompt (instead of `echo -n`).

With all of these changes, here's what your script looks like:

```
IFS= read -r -p "Enter description: " input
echo "$input"
```

Comment: Sometimes it is much better to point someone to FAQ instead of reinventing the wheel. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#read_.24foo and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo