# Get input from user to path which contains a space (bash-script)

Tags: bash

I need to prompt the user for a folder-path to SCP that folder from a server to my computer.

Since I know that there's a space in the folder-name (which cannot be omitted, unfortunately) I try to make that work, but I cant.

Currently I have

```sh
#copy.sh
read -r -p "Plot date: " plot_date
scp -r user@server:/home/user/Documents/projects/pages/$plot_date Plots/
```

where I know that `plot_date` is on the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm` e.g `2021-09-06 10.51`, but that does not work e.g:

```sh
./copy.sh
Plot date: 2021-09-06 10.51
user@server's password: *******
scp: /home/user/Documents/projects/pages/2021-09-06: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '17.10': No such file or directory
```

which seems like, it splits up the date and the hour.

I have tried include some double-quotes based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337385/bash-preserve-string-with-spaces-input-on-command-line) SO answer i.e

```sh
#copy.sh
read -r -p "Plot date: " plot_date
scp -r user@server:/home/user/Documents/projects/pages/"$plot_date" Plots/
```

which throws almost the same error

```
scp: /home/user/Documents/projects/pages/2021-09-06: No such file or directory
scp: 17.10: No such file or directory
```

I have tried save the input into another variable and use that (to ommit the string in the path)

```sh
read -r -p "Plot date: " plot_date
p_date="$plot_date"
scp -r user@server:/home/user/Documents/projects/pages/$p_date Plots/
```

which throws the same error as just above.

Atlast I have tried putting the entire path in a string i.e

```sh
read -r -p "Plot date: " plot_date
p_date="$plot_date"
scp -r "user@server:/home/user/Documents/projects/pages/$plot_date" Plots/
```

which throws the same error as the bottom 2 errors.

Now I'm really out of things to try

EDIT:

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858176/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-path-for-scp-copy-in-linux) is regarding the user input, which forces the user to input as `2021-09-09\ 17\.51`. I want to do the handling in the script i.e making the user able to just write `2021-09-06 17.51` as input

Comment: Sort of - the issue is though that I want to do that in the script and not in the input (that forces the user to write it as `2021-09-06\ 10\.51`)

Comment: Look at the answer using parameter expansion to escape spaces automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both ends are using bash, you can use `@Q` parameter expansion:

```
read -r -p "Plot date: " plot_date
scp -r user@server:/home/user/Documents/projects/pages/"${plot_date@Q}" Plots/
```

> ```
> ${parameter@operator}
>     Parameter transformation.  The expansion is either a transforma‐
>     tion of the value of parameter or  information  about  parameter
>     itself,  depending on the value of operator.  Each operator is a
>     single letter:
>
>     Q      The expansion is a string that is the value of  parameter
>             quoted in a format that can be reused as input.
> ```